How to stop every keystroke I make automatically copying to the Search field?
Every time I press a key on the keyboard it is automatically copied to the search field in the Launchpad. How can I stop this?

OS: mac os 14.5

Is this happening in the Finder? What app are you using? (You have 19 apps open as shown in the Dock.) Which Search field (there are many throughout macOS)? What version of macOS? There's so much missing information in your question it is impossible to help!

@IconDaemon It does not matter which app is open. It happens with every stroke.
mac os 14.5

if you try killing the dock, does that clear things up?

So, you have Pages open with an empty document, press a letter key, and instead of having the letter being shown in the document, LaunchPad opens?

killall Dock solved the problem thank you

@nohillside it showed the letter in the empty document and when I opened the launchpad it showed the letter in the search field as well.

The Launchpad is apart of the Dock. Sometimes it acts up. In this case, if you kill the Dock in Terminal or in Activity Monitor, it will restart and resolve this issue.
